# Editing Data in Child Window with RIA Services and Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

Is it possible to edit data in a SilverLight Child window when using RIA Services and Silverlight 4?   It sounds like a simple enough question, but I have not been able to get any combination of scenarios to work.

Simply put, I am viewing data in a grid that was populated through a DomainDataSource.  Instead of editing the data on the same screen (this is the pattern that ALL of the Microsoft samples seem to use), I want to open a child window, edit the data and return. Surely this is a common design pattern.

If anyone knows of a sample out there that uses this pattern, a link would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Rick Arthur

Comment: +1 for (this is the pattern that ALL of the Microsoft samples seem to use)

Answer (score 0):

This is a [Microsoft sample that uses a ChildWindow](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/RiaServices/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=2387). It uses RIA services, but not MVVM.

It doesn't fix a problem I'm having where [entities get attached to my context before I want them to be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243341/how-to-prevent-silverlight-ria-entity-getting-attached-as-new-before-im-ready), but does what you're looking for other than that.

Here's the relevant code to save you downloading the zip:

```
private void addNewEmployee_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        EmployeeRegistrationWindow addEmp = new EmployeeRegistrationWindow();
        addEmp.Closed += new EventHandler(addEmp_Closed);
        addEmp.Show();
    }

public partial class EmployeeRegistrationWindow : ChildWindow
    {
        public EmployeeRegistrationWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            NewEmployee = new Employee();
            addEmployeeDataForm.CurrentItem = NewEmployee;
            addEmployeeDataForm.BeginEdit();    
        }

        private void OKButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            addEmployeeDataForm.CommitEdit();
            this.DialogResult = true;
        }

        private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            NewEmployee = null;
            addEmployeeDataForm.CancelEdit();
            this.DialogResult = false;
        }

        public Employee NewEmployee { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The MVVM light Toolkit found [here](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/getstarted/) has  messeging between viewmodels for more information check above site. Please write if u need an example.